# My app doesn't appear on the "Complete action using" list

Tags: android, intentfilter

I have this code which download files from the internet. I'd like to open this downloaded file using my app when user clicks on the DownloadManager's notification (after the file is downloaded). Now (with the current intent-filter) my app appears on the "Complete action using" list only when user try to open it using file browser. When I click on the DownloadManager's notification my app is not on the list among apps able to open this file.

downloader method:

```
private void downloadPls(Uri uri)  {

   // String url = "url you want to download";
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
    request.setDescription("Some descrition");
    request.setTitle("Some title");

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    }
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "playlist.pls");

            // get download service and enqueue file
    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    manager.enqueue(request);

}
```

filter:

```
     <intent-filter>

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:host="*" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/x-scpls" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pls" />

        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Try splitting this into two filters. One uses `file`, `*`, and your `pathPattern`, while the other uses the `mimeType`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I guess the problem was caused by the `"android:scheme"` as it revealed to be `android:scheme="content://"` and no the `android:scheme="file"`.